# Null result on Converting NSData to NSString

Tags: objective-c, ios, asyncsocket

I am facing a problem when converting `NSData` to `NSString`. I'm using `UTF8Enconding` but the result is `null`!!

Here is the data I receive `<100226ab c0a8010b 00000000 00000000>` it must be either `192.168.1.11` or `192.168.1.17`.

This is the method I use to convert :

```
 NSString *ipAddress = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:address encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Is there anything wrong?!

By the way, This the `did receive data` delegate of `GCDAsyncUdpSocket` library.

Comment: have you checked nslogging `address` is it containing anything?

Comment: Yes, like I said, its <100226ab c0a8010b 00000000 00000000>

Comment: refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2467844/convert-utf-8-encoded-nsdata-to-nsstring

Comment: @Danialzo: please check my answer, and say are you doing similar way

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the documentation of `GCDAsyncUdpSocket`:

> The `localAddress` method returns a sockaddr structure wrapped in a
>   NSData object.

The following code unwraps the data to a [sockaddr structure](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696799/basedefs/sys/socket.h.html) and converts the IP address to a `NSString`. It works with IPv4 and IPv6 addresses.

```
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netdb.h>

NSData *data = ...; // your data
NSLog(@"data = %@", data);

// Copy data to a "sockaddr_storage" structure.
struct sockaddr_storage sa;
socklen_t salen = sizeof(sa);
[data getBytes:&sa length:salen];

// Get host from socket address as C string:
char host[NI_MAXHOST];
getnameinfo((struct sockaddr *)&sa, salen, host, sizeof(host), NULL, 0, NI_NUMERICHOST);

// Convert C string to NSString:
NSString *ipAddress = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:host length:strlen(host) encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"strAddr = %@", ipAddress);
```

*Output:*

```
data = <100226ab c0a8010b 00000000 00000000>
strAddr = 192.168.1.11
```

Comment: @Danialzo: You are welcome, and Merry Christmas to everybody!

Answer (score 2):

This is not a string response. This is binary data. If you consider `<100226ab c0a8010b 00000000 00000000>`, look at the `coa8010b`: `c0` in hex is equal to 192 in decimal, `a8` = 168, `01` = 1, and `0b` = 11. In short, this is a binary representation, not a string representation, of 192.168.1.11.

You may want to more carefully examine the `GCDAsyncUdpSocket` documentation for the nature of  response you should get, as it's apparently binary data, not a string.

Answer (score 0):

I guess there is problem with the encoding . I have also faced similar issue and solved by:

```
NSString *responseString =[[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:[data bytes] length:[data length] encoding:NSUnicodeStringEncoding];
```

Comment: this return some nonsense character -- see below 

ဂ⚫삨ċ

Comment: Please check this answer i have referred this to solve my problem:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10178936/nsdata-to-nsstring-returns-null

Comment: Danialzo's data is not a string. It's binary data.

Answer (score 0):

Found a much quicker way to do it, using `inet_ntoa()`:

```
//Get the bytes from the data and cast it to the correct struct
struct sockaddr_in *addr = (struct sockaddr_in *)[address bytes];
//inet_ntoa converts from the binary format to a C string
NSString *IP = [NSString stringWithCString:inet_ntoa(addr->sin_addr) encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
```

Answer (score -1):

```
First try with other encoding formats available

 1. NSASCIIStringEncoding
 2. NSMacOSRomanStringEncoding
 3. NSShiftJISStringEncoding.

even if it not works,try like the following ways

 1. NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:URL];
// Assuming data is in UTF8.
NSString *string = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:[data bytes]];

 2. This is like as you done.

// if data is in another encoding, for example ISO-8859-1
NSString *string = [[NSString alloc]
            initWithData:data encoding: NSISOLatin1StringEncoding];
```