# error when fetching NSUserDefaults object?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsuserdefaults

So i set up this method to retrieve my user defaults. It's supposed to check if the key contains anything. If not, it returns nil. If so, it returns the object. Very simple right? No matter what, if the object is not present, it crashes. It doesn't get past this method, either. If the object is nil, it continues into the if statement ANYWAYS and crashes where it's commented. i dont understand why its continuing into the if statement instead of skipping to else and moving on. however, if the object is present in defaults, the app works perfectly. any ideas?

```
+ (PAUserObject *)fetchDataSetWithDefaults {
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    id data = [defaults objectForKey:kPAUserDefaultsStorage];

 // at ^^^ this point, data is nil (as it should be)

    NSLog(@"MY KEY - %@", data);
 // ^^^ Still (correctly) nil

    if([defaults objectForKey:kPAUserDefaultsStorage]){ // <--- This should return nil, since it printed as nil in the last 2 statements
        NSData *thisData = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:kPAUserDefaultsStorage]; // <--- What the %$#@? it entered the if statement anyways?

        NSLog(@"Encoded Array - %@", thisData);
        PAUserObject *userObject = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:thisData]; // <--- CRASH
        NSLog(@"decoding data");
        return userObject;
    } else { // <--- DOESNT EVEN REACH THIS CODE!!! WTF
        return nil;
    }
}
```

**DEBUGGING STEPS**

I placed breakpoints and checked variable values all the way down until it crashed. that's definitely the line on which it crashes, as far as i can tell

**ERROR MESSAGE:**

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]: object cannot be nil'
```

Comment: What error message do you get when it crashes?

Comment: Do you use KVO in this project?

Comment: i havent completed the setup for it, but it's in a completely different part of the app. it's not directly related to whats happening here. but yes i do.

Comment: When it enters the if statement, the thisData is still nil?

Comment: Hmm.. What if it is not really nil? Its an NSData object right? It could be a format error that makes it look like nil. Check out this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10178936/nsdata-to-nsstring-returns-null

Comment: but when i add an object to that key in defaults, the code works. and when i print the NSUserDefaults keys out, mine isnt listed

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54475/discussion-between-george-sach-and-deathstalker).

Comment: I'd look at where you're setting the object for the key in NSUserDefaults. I was able to reproduce your problem by adding an empty NSData object for that key `[defaults setObject:[NSData data] forKey:kPAUserDefaultsStorage];` but without a crash (so maybe the data your adding is invalid somehow).

Comment: im not adding any. this is me testing if the object is empty or not. theres nothing in it yet

Comment: do i have to initialize nsuserdefaults with a nil value for the key im using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, you error is obvious: **you can't pass a `nil` object to that function**.

But, i copied your code...and apologize, but **it works properly**..

```
#define kPAUserDefaultsStorage @"key"

+ (NSString *)fetchDataSetWithDefaults {
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    id data = [defaults objectForKey:kPAUserDefaultsStorage];

    // at ^^^ this point, data is nil (as it should be)

    NSLog(@"MY KEY - %@", data);
    // ^^^ Still (correctly) nil

    if([defaults objectForKey:kPAUserDefaultsStorage]){ // <--- This should return nil, since it printed as nil in the last 2 statements
        NSData *thisData = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:kPAUserDefaultsStorage]; // <--- What the %$#@? it entered the if statement anyways?

        NSLog(@"Encoded Array - %@", thisData);
        // <--- CRASH
        NSLog(@"decoding data");

        return @"IS NOT NIL";
    } else { // <--- DOESNT EVEN REACH THIS CODE!!! WTF
        return @"IS NIL";
    }
}
```

Called from here:

```
 NSLog(@"%@", [[self class] fetchDataSetWithDefaults]);
```

And the console log:

```
2014-05-26 23:32:36.450 Test[11540:60b] MY KEY - (null)
2014-05-26 23:32:44.886 Test[11540:60b] IS NIL
```

Comment: thats true, by the error, it does seem obvious. i cant pass nil to that function. however, if you notice, im not using an array in that code anywhere. im not using an array in the project at all. the project is only a few days old. so im not sure why its even giving that error. in fact, at no point at all am i passing anything to nsuserdefaults. im just trying to read from it, nothing else

Comment: Please, try to cancel the app on the simulator (or device), clean the project and run again.

Comment: no good. do i have to initialize the nsuserdefaults key before using it? even if it has a nil value? because currently, the key doesnt exist at all

Comment: wow. you have to register the defaults. i had no idea. i dont use them often

Comment: No you don't need to register it. I haven't registered it. If the key doesn't exits return nil